# How to use array element in \ifthenelse?

Tags: arrays, string, latex

For a small project I have to work with arrays as a data structure in latex. I've been spending hours and hours to make this work, but it just doesn't work. I've been trying many different implementations for arrays, but nothing works the way I want it to work. I think the problem is the way in which the characters are stored in the array. The problem is I need an array as data structure, but it can't access the characters stored in it when using macros like \equal.

Here's the simplified code I want to work (the \equal line gives an error, so there's no way I can compare the characters stored in the array with an actual character):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={17cm, 25.7cm}, left=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}

\newarray\testvalues
\testvalues(1)={K}
\testvalues(2)={B}
\testvalues(3)={I}
\testvalues(4)={D}
\testvalues(5)={G}

\newcounter{i}
\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i}<6}{
\testvalues(\value{i})
\ifthenelse{\equal{\testvalues(\value{i})}{K}}{has K!}{has not K!}
}

\end{document}
```

I've been trying everything available on the internet. Just nothing seems to work. Please help.